# Trying to build OpenCV sfm on Windows: Ceres_DIR-NOTFOUND

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.1, ceres-solver

I tried to build OpenCV with sfm module, following this tutorial:

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fqiita.com%2FChaoticActivity%2Fitems%2F3888e886925ef0f84926&sandbox=1.

My operating system is Windows 7 without admin permission.

First I downloaded Eigen, then I managed to build the glog library, after that the gflag, suitespase and metis and finally the ceres solver library. After building the ceres solver, there is no Folder C:\Programs\ceres, which is specified as cmake_prefix_install path. The ceresconfig.cmake file is missing also.

My question is: Should both the folder and .cmake file be there? Or is the ceres_dir OpenCV , a completely different folder?